# Node app deployed on Heroku immediately crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

***fixed, thank you all who helped.

Hello thank you for attempting to help me. I have looked through google and here for a fix but to no avail.  This is the first question I have asked so if I'm not clear or specific enough I apologize and will try to clear it up as best as I can.

I have recently deployed an app on heroku using a free dyno(their node.js buildpack).

This app runs perfectly fine on my localhost.  When I start the deploy process and check the logs I am met with this error:

```
    2021-05-16T21:03:07.870774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-16T21:03:14.868295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-16T21:03:18.871696+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T21:03:18.871706+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-05-16T21:03:18.871707+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2021-05-16T21:03:18.871707+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T21:03:19.162417+00:00 app[web.1]: [33m[nodemon] 2.0.7[39m
2021-05-16T21:03:19.167339+00:00 app[web.1]: [33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[39m
2021-05-16T21:03:19.167341+00:00 app[web.1]: [33m[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*[39m
2021-05-16T21:03:19.167341+00:00 app[web.1]: [33m[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json[39m
2021-05-16T21:03:19.167342+00:00 app[web.1]: [32m[nodemon] starting `node index.js index.js`[39m
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271336+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271342+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271342+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271343+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271343+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271379+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271580+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271587+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271587+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: []
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271588+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-16T21:03:19.279342+00:00 app[web.1]: [31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m
2021-05-16T21:04:15.043653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-05-16T21:04:15.098622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-05-16T21:04:15.255205+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-05-16T21:04:15.331085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have tried changing my start script to not include nodemon, I have tried moving my index.js to app/index.js as it says in that log, I've tried changing the start script with any combination of "node index.js" "nodemon index.js"

I have no clue why it won't work properly.  At the end of that log it also times out due to not binding with the $PORT even though I have it set as process.env.PORT.

Any suggestions are welcomed and if I need to provide any more code, please let me know.

Here is the file structure for the app:
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdN6P.png)

Here is the structure of my index.js:
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAFSq.png)

Comment: Can you share the file structure of your node app? Is `index.js` present in the root?

Comment: Just updated with pictures of file structure and index.js.  It is in the root of the project. thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the reason why it's failing

```
[32m[nodemon] starting `node index.js index.js`[39m
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271336+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271342+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
```

I Think your node run script is wrong its trying to run
`node index.js index.js`

Check your Package.json file

**Potential Problem 2**

If not the above then 2nd issue I see is the path of index.js

```
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271343+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271379+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
2021-05-16T21:03:19.271580+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
```

do you have the index.js at the same level as package.json OR is it located inside of a folder?
Because as you see the Error Log it says cannot load module `/app/index.js`
[assuming `/app/` is your root folder]

This can also happen if the file starts with Capital **I** and in node script you have small **i** or vice a versa

Comment: I thought that was the problem as well, but my start scripts are as follows:

`"start": "node index.js",
"dev":"nodemon index.js",`

Comment: That was exactly it... Thank you so much Nishant, I feel like an idiot for that.  Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your main error but need to set your environment variabels seperately for heroku, heroku does not read from your local .env file.

You can set these by going to your app and then under settings->config vars, here you can just copy and paste the key/values from your .env file one by one.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! I should've added in my main post that I already have my config vars set up through heroku.  From my understanding it should read any variables I set through the dashboard or heroku CLI as 'process.env.VARIABLE' or is that incorrect? I had a PORT variable prior to deploying but I removed it due to heroku using their own ports.

Comment: Yes, you can still use them as normal as you would trough your .env file.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it but that's good to know for the future, thank you.